# Como concatenar strings sem utilizar função?

Tags: c, string

Boa tarde galera, estou com esta dúvida. Como faço pra concatenar duas strings sem que utilize função ou biblioteca para isso?

Comment: Acho que não tem como. Pelo que eu saiba, a linguagem C infelizmente não é como PHP ou JS que um + ou . entre 2 strings gera a concatenação.

Comment: As strings em C são só arrays de char (caracteres). Se não me engano, você não pode concatenar diretamente strings em C, precisa usar a função `strcat()` para isso.

Comment: Alguém deu voto negativo na pergunta e em todas as respostas. Poderia explicar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você cria uma nova string com o tamanho suficiente e copia os caracteres das duas strings na nova criada. O tamanho é a soma dos tamanhos das outras duas strings. A cópia de cada string pode ser feita com um `for` para cada.

Ou seja:

```
char a[] = "teste1";
char b[] = "teste2";

int tamanho1 = 0;
while (a[tamanho1]) tamanho1++;

int tamanho2 = 0;
while (b[tamanho2]) tamanho2++;

int tamanho3 = tamanho1 + tamanho2 + 1;
char *c = (char *) malloc(tamanho3);

for (int i = 0; a[i]; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i];
}

for (int i = 0; b[i]; i++) {
    c[i + tamanho1] = b[i];
}

c[tamanho1 + tamanho2] = 0;
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/FXU7af)

Entretanto, não recomendo fazer isso. A tendência ao fazer isso é a de reinventar a roda múltiplas vezes, o que é desnecessário, confuso e muito propenso a erros. A função `strlen` substitui esses dois `while`s. A função `strcat` poderia ser usada para eliminar os `for`s.

Comment: Me ajudou muito, obrigado Victor!! Entendi agora a ideia de como cocatenar as strings.

Comment: @AdrielGama Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. :)

Answer (score 1):

Há diversos modos de fazer concatenação de strings. Segue alguns exemplos que são mais práticos e menos custosos.

```
char * str1 = "Teste1";
char * str1 = "Teste2";
char str3[50];

/* Exemplo 1 */
memcpy(str3, str1, 6);
memcpy(str3[6], str2, 6); // str3: "Teste1Teste2"  

/* Exemplo 2 */
memcpy(str3, str1, 6);
memcpy(str3[6], "", 1);
memcpy(str3[7], str2, 6); // str3: "Teste1 Teste2"
```

Comment: Para obter o tamanho do array você tambèm pode usar: `sizeof(char) / sizeof(str1[0]);`

Answer (score -1):

Você pode iterar pelo array de caracteres da segunda string e ir adicionando um a um no fim da primeira string.

```
char str1[100], str2[100], i, j;
//Conta o tamanho da primeira string (poderia usar strlen) - \0 é o fim da string

for(i=0; str1[i]!='\0'; ++i); 

// O segundo loop concatena cada caracter da segunda string ao fim da primeira. 
// Teste antes para não estourar o tamanho máximo da primeira.

for(j=0; str2[j]!='\0'; ++j, ++i) {
  str1[i]=str2[j];
}

str1[i]='\0';
```

Não sei porque você usaria algo assim, já que teria que implementar todos os controles de novo, mas é por aí.

Comment: Professor pediu pra gerar um email automático a partir de apenas uma entrada contendo nome completo da pessoa, utilizando strings. A ideia é pegar o primeiro nome, o ultimo nome, colocar um ponto entre os dois e imprimir tudo isso com o @dominio que você escolher. Mas tudo isso sem utilizar função alguma.

Comment: Entendi, é puramente didático. Desse jeito muito básico que eu respondi funcionaria, desde que você concatenasse o ponto “.” Entre as strings (nomes) e adicionasse o domínio depois. É a mesma lógica. Você realmente entendeu a resposta que você marcou como certa? Ela usa uma função.